# Check for value in delimitted field via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Db table with a csv field called "Line".
There are several values in the field separated by semicolons.

I am trying to find a LINQ expression to check if there is any row where the second value in the "Line" field has a specific value.

Something like:

```
if (dbContext.Test.Any(t => Array.IndexOf(t.Line.Split(';'), value) = 1))
{
Do something ...                          
}
```

Example:

```
Line = "value1;apple;value3;value4"
if (dbContext.Test.Any("second value in Line field equals 'apple'"))
{
Do something ...
}
```

What's the most straight-forward and concise way to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] to include an example of a 'good' row and a 'bad' row.

Comment: Your real problem here is your DB design.  If possible change it to not store multiple values like that.

Comment: Do you use EF? If it's so do you want the database to proof or your client? This makes a different in the code...

Comment: I know the problem is the DB design. The problem is I do not have any influence to that since it is a provided table of a third party Interface.

Comment: Well you could always pull the data with `AsEnumerable` and do the parsing in code.  SQL isn't particularly good with parsing logic.  And I'm not even sure what you would need to do in EF to get the correct SQL to do this.

Comment: Also instead of a `Where(...) != null` maybe you actual want `Any(...)` as `Where` shouldn't be returning `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be using a `DbContext` and there's no mechanism to translate splitting a string or searching by index you'll need to get more data than necessary, then filter in linq-to-objects.  You could to an initial basic filter to limit the number of rows coming back, but you'll need to do the remaining filtering in-memory:

```
var queryEF = dbContext.Test
                       .Where(t => t.Line.Contains(";" + value" + ";");

var queryMemory = queryEF.AsEnumerable()   // shift to Linq-to-Objects
                         .Where((t => Array.IndexOf(t.Line.Split(';'), value) == 1);

if (queryMemory.Any())
{
    //Do something ...
}
```

Comment: For the Array.IndexOf... I get the error "This expression cannot be used as an assignment target".

Comment: @Palmi typo.  Use `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the value Linq is a simple method for this.

Just do the following:

1. Take the column
2. Splitt it's content
3. If there is more than one Element in the splitted list continue
4. Proof whether the second element is what you are looking for.

You should consider to normalize your data, because of storing redundant/unnormalized data could cause other problems.

**EDIT**

Ok, working with linq in this case is not as easy as i thought, because we do not have any index information. This is easy and should work:

```
string line = "value1;apple;value3;value4";
string[] splitted = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
if (splitted.Length > 1 && splitted[1] == "apple")
{
    Console.WriteLine("APPLE!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, your table (dbContext) contains a collection of rows (Test)?

You can use 'where' to reduce that collection down to only elements that meet the condition (in this case, I split the string by the semi-colon and see if the second string is equal to apple. 'Any' will then return true if there were one or more matches.

```
        if(dbContext.Test.Where(x => x.Line.Split(';')[1] == "apple").Any())
        {
            // Do the thing
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason that speaks against doing it like this as well: if(dbContext.Test.Any(x => x.Line.Split(';')[1] == "apple"))?

Comment: Get error: The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.